# use of Find function

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a code there I need to find out a string "total" OR "totals"
I tried this code

```
Set lRow = ws.Range(nRow & ":" & aRow).Find(what:="total" OR "totals", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
```

I Also tried this

```
Set lRow = ws.Range(nRow & ":" & aRow).Find(what:="total" OR what:="totals", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
```

Is it possible to use FIND function like this. If not the pls guide me the way to find out one of these two string.

Comment: if you do not have anything other than `total` or `totals` for example `Total Recall` then you can use wildcard. `what:="total*"`

Comment: @SiddharthRout From now on, every variable I use for a sum will be named `TotalRecall`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't search like that.  The workaround, however, is easy

```
Set lRow = ws.Range(nRow & ":" & aRow).Find(what:="total", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
If lRow Is Nothing then 
   Set lRow = ws.Range(nRow & ":" & aRow).Find(what:="totals", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
End If
```

Note that this process can be extended for as many conditions as you would like to check for, assuming that they are exclusive

Comment: excellent, Thank a lot to tell me about this way. I will use this method in my coding.
But here I want to clear a doubt that if I use "total*" as suggested by Mr Siddharth will this find "totalD" or anything else which is suffix of "total" ?

Comment: And what result will I get if more than one "total" is present in the sheet OR range specified in function?

Comment: @Nafis if more than one total is present, it will only find the first one in the specified range.  Siddharth's will find anything that starts with "total", but the find function always returns the first found instance.

Answer (score 2):

Because "total" is a *sub-string* of "totals", we can search for "total" using **xlPart** to find either word:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lRow As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set lRow = ws.Range("A:A").Find(what:="total", after:=Range("A1"), lookat:=xlPart)
    MsgBox lRow.Address(0, 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: While true, this won't work if OP had something like "subtotal" that they _didn't_ want to find